# css decendance question

Tags: css

I'm trying to figure out what the first descendant means.
I understand the second is saying take all classes with the name tank and all the li descendants and any children with the class open that has a span tag and set that span to a with of 333px

The first one is different in that li.open? What is that saying.

```
.tank li.open span {
    width: 333px;
}

.tank li .open span {
    width: 333px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li.open` says *select all `li` elements which **also** have the `open` class*.

For example, the selector `.tank li.open span` would match the `span` where...

```
<ol class="tank">
   <li class="open">
      <span>Hello</span>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex but wouldn't .tank li .open span also say that

Comment: @Chapster Nope, that would mean the `li` had to be a descendent of an element with the `open` class.

Comment: Thanks Alex for clearing that up for me. Is there a good book or tutorial out there that explains the descendant relationship like I just asked about. Not sure if there are more I should be aware of. Maybe I should open another question on just that.

Comment: @Chapster I don't have any book recommendations, just use Google a lot :)